# How to mimic Photoshop "Color Overlay" in CSS

Tags: css, gradient, photoshop

I have a button designed with Photoshop. The button has a gradient defined and I know how to generate it using [Ultimate CSS Gradients Tool](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

The problem is the button also has a 'Color Overlay' and I don't know how to convert it to css terms?!

**UPDATE:**

O.K, just to clarify, I know CSS quite well and i know how to set styles to elements.

I have this gradient:

```
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
        background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(179,183,189,1) 0%, rgba(106,114,125,1) 85%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(179,183,189,1)), color-stop(85%,rgba(106,114,125,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(179,183,189,1) 0%,rgba(106,114,125,1) 85%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(179,183,189,1) 0%,rgba(106,114,125,1) 85%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(179,183,189,1) 0%,rgba(106,114,125,1) 85%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(179,183,189,1) 0%,rgba(106,114,125,1) 85%); /* W3C */
```

But like i mentioned, In photoshop there is also a Color Overlat defined which makes the button a bit darker, so in photoshop the button looks darker then in the browser, So my question is how do i combine the gradient and the Color Overlay in one CSS rule to make the button look exactly the same as in photoshop.

Comment: Use color picker, select the top color, select the bottom color, com'on it's not that tough

Comment: I answered your question :)

Comment: ??????????????? Why so rude?

Comment: @Mr.Alien - Sorry, language barrier, wasn't aware it's so rude :(, will remove it

Comment: @ftom2 if coloroverlay is what i think, its just a tone down(darker) than the ones you choose, just capture the values (javascript) and decrease a number or two

Comment: Did you read my answer below?

Comment: @Mr.Alien opacity dont make things darker, are you nuts?

Comment: @Mr.Alien - i did now, didn't see before you updated it, will try it. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Ark It's a color overlay, the darker the opacity, the darker is the overlay

Comment: "the darker the opacity" lol

Comment: @Ark You seriously don't understand CSS right? http://jsfiddle.net/x9L9B/2/

Comment: @Mr.Alien the concept of opacity, a great example of opaque object is the mirror, they dont let light pass out, when you decrease opacity youre just turning it more "transparent", web object are by default 100% opaque, you dont turn then darker or brighter, thats why i lol...sorry for the misunderstood, like ftom2 said, its internet/language barrier

Comment: @Ark It's ok, but what I meant was that he can control the overlay with an opaque overlay div :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien absolutly, thats why i upvoted you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/x9L9B/)

A little better button [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/x9L9B/1/)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/x9L9B/2/) with overlay

Just declare a class for button say `.design`

```
.design {
   /* Gradient code goes here */
}
```

Now you can use this class as follows

```
<button class="design">Designed Button</button>
```

OR

```
<input type="button" class="design" value="Designed Button" />
```

> For the COLOR OVERLAY, you can wrap the button inside a div with
>   `display: inline-block` and `position: relative` so that it will wrap
>   the button appropriately and use another div which is `positioned
>   absolute` inside the `wrapper div` with a height and width defined as
>   `100%` and assign opaque background color using `rgba()` and define
>   opacity as needed

Also if you want to be precise with your CSS declarations, you can particularly define `.design` class as `input[type=button].design` or `button.design` whatever you use, so that `.design` will not be applied to any other element